# Initialization of inline static class member

Tags: c++, inline, static-members

I have a following class:

```cpp
struct A
{
    inline static int a = 0; // OK
    static int b = 0;        // error: non-const static data member must be initialized out of line
};
```

I know that static variable `b` can't be initialized like in the example.
But why can I initialize if it is `inline`?